# .Net Framework 4.5. Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction

Tags: .net-4.5, distributed-transactions, objectcontext, change-tracking

I´m working on a distributed transaction issue that occurs using NET Framework 4.5. If I try to execute the app on a machine (and Dev Server also) using Framework 4.0 the components work fine.
         The problem started when I installed the fwk4.5 on my machine and run It on. I only installed the framework, I never changed the source code neither changed target framework on assemblies.

I need to know why It is happening, if the behavior of Entity Framework and distributed transactions have been  changed after fwk4.0.

I read a lot but I couldn´t figure It out yet. 
Any help would be very apreciated.

Best Regards,
Diego

Here you can see a simple code sample where I could reproduce the error:

Note: Notice that if the ObjectContext connection is not opened manually before transaction It works fine.

```
public static bool DoTran_ObjectContext()
        {
            String strc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB2Entities"].ConnectionString; //"metadata=res://*/TestDb2Model.csdl|res://*/TestDb2Model.ssdl|res://*/TestDb2Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=TestDB2;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework""
            ObjectContext oc = new ObjectContext(strc);

            //this line causes enlist error at the end of function/////
            oc.Connection.Open();
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////

            var t = (from s in oc.CreateObjectSet() where s.Id == 2 select s).FirstOrDefault();

            t.Valor = "Cambiado_" + DateTime.Now;

            using (TransactionScope scope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
            {

                String cstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; //"Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB2;Integrated Security=True";
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(cstr);
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Tabla1_Db2 values('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "')";

                SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                cmd.Transaction = tran;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                tran.Commit();
                conn.Close();

                oc.SaveChanges();

                scope2.Complete();
            }

            //On this line the error is thrown
            var t2 = (from s in oc.CreateObjectSet() where s.Id == 2 select s).FirstOrDefault();

            return true;
        }
```

**Error:**

```
"Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction."
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to IsolationLevel being different in one of the scopes as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746.aspx)

> When using nested TransactionScope objects, all nested scopes must be configured to use exactly the same isolation level if they want to join the ambient transaction. If a nested TransactionScope object tries to join the ambient transaction yet it specifies a different isolation level, an ArgumentException is thrown.

By default isolation level is Serializable, you're setting your Transaction to be ReadCommitted, if your caller runs a Serializable transaction you're involved in it.